# Linux command or Bash syntax that calculate the next ASCII character

Tags: linux, perl, bash, awk

I have a Linux machine ([Red Hat Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux) 5.1), and I need to add the following task to my Bash script.

Which Linux command or Bash syntax will calculate the next ASCII character?

Remark – the command syntax can be also [AWK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK)/Perl, but this syntax must be in my Bash script.

Example:

```
 input                  results

 a    --> the next is   b
 c    --> the next is   d
 A    --> the next is   B
```

Comment: what do you want to happen if your input is z/Z?

Comment: this isnt logical case (I need until z or Z !!!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl's [`++` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Auto-increment-and-Auto-decrement) also handles strings, to an extent:

```
perl -nle 'print ++$_'
```

The `-l` option with autochomp is necessary here, since `a\n` for example will otherwise return `1`.

Answer (score 8):

Use translate (`tr`):

```
echo "aA mM yY" | tr "a-yA-Y" "b-zB-Z"
```

It prints:

`bB nN zZ`

Comment: perfect use for tr. With bash, you could write `printf '%s -> next is %s\n' "$input" "$(tr 'a-yA-Y' 'b-zB-Z' <<< "$input")"`

Answer (score 3):

You could use `chr()` and `ord()` functions for Bash (see *[How do I convert an ASCII character to its decimal (or hexadecimal) value and back?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/071)*):

```
# POSIX
# chr() - converts decimal value to its ASCII character representation
# ord() - converts ASCII character to its decimal value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -le "print chr(ord(<>) + 1)"
```

Interactive:

```
breqwas@buttonbox:~$ perl -le "print chr(ord(<>) + 1)"
M
N
```

Non-interactive:

```
breqwas@buttonbox:~$ echo a | perl -le "print chr(ord(<>) + 1)"
b
```

Comment: This doesn't limit itself to ASCII input or output.

Answer (score 0):

The character value:

```
c="a"
```

To convert the character to its ASCII value:

```
v=$(printf %d "'$c")
```

The value you want to add to this ASCII value:

```
add=1
```

To change its ASCII value by adding $add to it:

```
((v+=add))
```

To convert the result to char:

```
perl -X -e "printf('The character is %c\n', $v);"
```

I used `-X` to disable all warnings

---

**You can combine all of these in one line and put the result in the vairable $r:**

```
c="a"; add=1; r=$(perl -X -e "printf('%c', $(($add+$(printf %d "'$c"))));")
```

you can print the result:

```
echo "$r"
```

---

**You can make a function to return the result:**

```
achar ()
{
     c="$1"; add=$2
     printf "$(perl -X -e "printf('%c', $(($add+$(printf %d "'$c"))));")"
}
```

you can use the function:

```
x=$(achar "a" 1) // x = the character that follows a by 1
```

or you can make a loop:

```
array=( a k m o )
for l in "${array[@]}"
do
     echo "$l" is followed by $(achar "$l" 1)
done
```